# Converting a String representing a mathemetical expression into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want to convert a String such as `1+40.2+(2)` into a String array `[1, +, 40.2, +, (, 2, )]` in order to use it as a parameter for a Shunting Yard algorithm in my Calculator class.

The input will be entered without spaces, so I can't just use `input.split("\\s+")`. I have come up with a long process involving ArrayLists, StringBuilders, and stacks, but I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this.

`input.split("")` won't work, since it would return `[1, +, 4, 0, ., 2, +, (, 2, )]`. This is actually the starting point of my current process, and I can post the pseudocode for it, if anyone is interested (although I'm having problems actually implementing my pseudocode).

Any advice or help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `java.io.StreamTokenizer` to see if that can help you!

Comment: I wouldn't use `split` at all.  Instead, determine a regex that represents one token, then use [`Matcher.lookingAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--) in a loop.  Make sure the regex starts with `\s*` to skip extra spaces.  For example, the regex could match a string of digits or perhaps two strings of digits separated by a decimal point, or any other single character you need to recognize (operator or parentheses or whatever).  Use a capture group and then append each `group(1)` to an `ArrayList`.

Comment: The elements of your array are what are called the *tokens* of the input, and the process of creating the array you want is sometimes called *tokenisation*.

Comment: I blew it--you can't really use `Matcher.lookingAt` in a loop because it doesn't find the "next occurrence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like the first answer, but if you want to try using Regex as suggested in second comment, here's a Regex that will match each element of your equation one by one so you can append to your list. Note that it assumes that all of the string consists of are decimal point numbers, operators, and parenthesis.

```
[0-9\.]+|[+\-*/]|[()]
```

Note that in character classes, any character except ^-]\ is a literal so that's why the character classes look a bit funny. To construct the corresponding Java pattern, use

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9\\.]+|[+\\-*/]|[()]")
```

Example:

```
String s = "1+40.2+(2)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9\\.]+|[+\\-*/]|[()]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
1
+
40.2
+
(
2
)
```

Comment: A flaw in this is that if there are any garbage characters, `find()` will skip over them.  That's why I first suggested using `lookingAt()`, to make sure the pattern was matched starting at the current point.  But that's bad--it causes an infinite loop.  One way to fix this is to put `\\G` at the beginning of the pattern, which means the next match must start at the end of the previous match.  Then if `m.find()` fails but there are more characters in the string, there must be a syntax error.  The pattern would also need `\\s*` somewhere to skip whitespace.

Comment: @ajb Where would you suggest putting `\\G` and `\\s*`? I'm still trying to learn regex and I'm not too sure. Here is the expression I'm using now, like 2359 Worker's but with `\\^` added: `Pattern.compile("[0-9\\.]+|[+\\-*/\\^]|[()]");`

Comment: @pez `"\\G\\s*([0-9\\.]+|[+\\-*/\\^]|[()])\\s*"`.  `\\G` forces any new match to start where the previous match left off, preventing `find()` from skipping over garbage characters that you would like to be reported as an error.  I put `\\s*` on both sides so that whitespace both at the beginning and end of the string will be skipped, as well as between tokens.  I also put the non-whitespace portion in `()`, which causes it to be a "capture group".  That means you'd use `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group()` and the whitespace would not be part of the group.

Answer (score 1):

The [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) string method should be able to help you. Use this to surround the tokens you want to pull out with a special dividing character (I arbitrarily chose ':', but any character/string you're confident won't actually be in the input will work). Then you can split on that character.

```
 String s = "1+40.2+(2)";
 String dividingToken = ":";
 String[] sSplit = s.replaceAll("\\+", dividingToken + "+" + dividingToken)
                    .replaceAll("\\(", dividingToken + "(" + dividingToken)
                    .replaceAll("\\)", dividingToken + ")" + dividingToken)
                    .split(dividingToken);
 for(String str: sSplit){
    System.out.println(str);
 }
```

Output:

```
1
+
40.2
+

(
2
)
```

You could easily loop .replaceAll over an array of tokens (["+", "-", "*", ...]) that you want to split up. Just remember to add "//" before it in replace all because many of them have special regex meaning, whereas you actually want to match "+".

Comment: Thanks! I implemented your code but also added `replaceAll` lines for the operators `- * / ^`, and also added `replaceAll("\\s+", "")` at the beginning to get rid of any potential whitespace. But I still get a whitespace character in the element of the array before `(`, just like you did. How do I get rid of that? I've encountered the same problem elsewhere before.